# PHP Changing Image Filename

Tags: php

I'm having a little bit of a pickle with changing over the image filename and can't get my head round it.  I'm trying to rename the image numbers, as in Image 3 can change to Image 1. Code below...

```
$chosenImg=$_GET['chosenImg'];

$imagerename=rename("../../images/$imgname-1.jpg","../../images/$imgname-temp.jpg");

$imagerename=rename("../../images/$chosenImg","../../images/$imgname-1.jpg");   

$imagerename=rename("../../images/$imgname-temp.jpg","../../images/$chosenImg");
```

Any help would be much appreciated, or if you have a simpler solution great!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't ever rely on user input, or you may end up renaming an important file... (my evil me would first try to rename /etc/passwd in this case)

Comment: Good point, I'll change the code over to a post setting and button instead of text link.

Comment: I don't see why your solution shouldn't work. But if you're displaying the images in a browser based on running a php script, I'd keep the image names the same and just push out new links.

Answer (score 0):

Oki I knew it was stupid and nothing I had done but something I had forgot.

The code works but using chrome and image changes you need to Force Refresh the page as chrome doesn't always refresh the image cache.  Damn you google chrome!